# Upload game but never found

Tags: ios

I upload my game from the Xcode and when I logged in Appstore developer account it doesn't appear in my Activity /  Builds . Should I take from my Xcode project something? or should I sync something ?
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiB4i.png)

Comment: Can show how you upload your game? any warning or error pops out?

Comment: Xcode / product / archive  and then do all the settings and send to App Store